# Replacing dots in URL for Django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a web application where I need IP addresses to be a URL parameter in Django.  However, I want to remove the dots as they aren't valid to use in a URL.  Maybe replace them with dashes?  Is there any good way of doing this?

Here is my model:

models.py

```
class Machine(models.Model):
    ip = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True) #255.255.255.255
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16, default="") #SSH-Server
    number_of_threats = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here is my view:

```
def machine(request, ip):
    print machine_ip
    ip = Machine.objects.get(ip=ip)
    context_dict['machine_ip'] = machine_ip
    return render(request, 'topology/machine.html', context_dict)
```

The format I have now is: /machine/192.168.1.1
The format I a want to have is: /machine/192-168-1-1 (or similar)

I looked at Slugify as it is does a similar function, but it doesn't look like it will do the same with dots.

Any suggestions on a good way of doing this?

Comment: Dots are perfectly valid for use in the path component of a URL:  `/foo/bar.html` ...

Comment: Could you just urlencode the IP address, changing the dots to `%2E`? That would at least give you valid URLs.

Comment: `.` will not create problem here.Then why you are trying to replace it ?

Comment: Do you have any reason not to use Django's GenericIPAddressField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def machine(request, ip):
    print machine_ip
    ip = Machine.objects.get(ip=ip)
    context_dict['machine_ip'] = machine_ip.replace('.', '-')
    return render(request, 'topology/machine.html', context_dict)
```

and in urls.py make parameter ip

```
(?P<ip>.*)
```

Comment: A stricter URL: `(?P<ip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})`